# I can't put a Greek letter into `\tag{...}`

Tags: support, mathjax

David Madore said this was a good place to report MathJax bugs, and I think I have encountered one.  Here is a formula tagged with the label “$FLT$”:

$$a^n + b^n = x^n \tag{FLT}$$

To get this I used `\tag{FLT}`.

Now I would like to label the following formula with “$F\Phi$”, analogously using `\tag{F\Phi}`, but it doesn't work:

$$a^n + b^n = x^n \tag{F\Phi}$$

Is this is a bug or a feature? If it's a feature, why?

Comment: I meant to post this on the meta site. I have flagged it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the expression inside the "tag" is interpreted as a text, not a math formula. Try this:

`$$a^n + b^n = x^n \tag{F$\Phi$}$$`

which yields

> $$a^n + b^n = x^n \tag{F$\Phi$}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$x^n+y^n=z^n \tag{$F\Phi$}$$
Use dollar signs around the F\Phi, since \tag switches to text mode. If you want $F$ upright, there are various fixes.

Why? It would not be attractive if default were math mode, since FLT would become $FLT$.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: You are welcome. At one point I helped a bit with a book on LaTeX, and learned many things that I have mostly forgotten.

Comment: Put the dollar signs only around the \Phi. (F$\Phi$)

Answer (score 4):

> Is this is a bug or a feature? If it's a feature, why?

It's a feature.  Note that that's how $\rm\LaTeX$'s `\tag{}` macro works (its argument is placed in text mode), so MathJax treats it the same way.